# while loop written too difficult

Tags: java

I wrote this code and its working, but I cant seem to find a way to write it a lot easier. Right now I am specifying all the possible situations and adding functions to them. Its doable if I only use two booleans variables (status1 and status2) like in the code below. But If I use more than 2 variables it is too much code I need to write.

```
while (!status1 || !status2) {
            if (!status1 && !status2) {
                jTextField1.setForeground(Color.red);
                jTextField2.setForeground(Color.red);
                break;
            } else if (!status1 && status2) {
                jTextField1.setForeground(Color.red);
                break;
            } else if (status1 && !status2) {
                jTextField2.setForeground(Color.red);
                break;
            }
```

Basically what I want to achieve is to write something like the code below ( without specifying all the possible situations). I tested this code but it only performs the first if statement and not the other ones.

What am i doing wrong? I want it to loop through all the if statements.

```
while (!status1 || !status2) {
            if (!status1 {
                jTextField1.setForeground(Color.red);
                break;
            } else if (!status2) {
                jTextField2.setForeground(Color.red);
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (!status1 || !status2 /* || !status3 || and so on*/) {
    boolean do_break=false;
    if (!status1) {
        jTextField1.setForeground(Color.red);
        do_break=true;
    } 
    if (!status2) {
        jTextField2.setForeground(Color.red);
        do_break=true;
    }
/*    if (!status3) {
        jTextField3.setForeground(Color.red);
        do_break=true;
    }*/
    if(do_break) break;

    here_the_part_that_you_omitted_from_the_question();//...
}
```

Please clarify if there is a loop body that you are not telling us about.

Answer (score 1):

The else is your problem. The breaks are also incorrect.

```
if (!status1) {
    jTextField1.setForeground(Color.red);
} 
if (!status2) {
    jTextField2.setForeground(Color.red);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but using this code makes my program unstable (as if it's in an infinite loop or something), thats why I used the breaks after each if statement. If I add the breaks, it will only perform the first if statement. What can we do about this?

Comment: You are correct, why is there a loop?. If you have one put the break after the if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see why you're using a `while` loop. What about something like this?

```
Color color1 = Color.red;
Color color2 = Color.red;

if (status1) {
    color1 = 0;
}

if (status2) {
    color2 = 0;
}

jTextField1.setForeground(color1);
jTextField2.setForeground(color2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the statement you wrote in the "while" statement is the same as the first "if" statement. If you write

> while (true)

instead, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simplified equivalent code for 
**your code:**

```
while (!status1 || !status2) {
            if (!status1 && !status2) {
                jTextField1.setForeground(Color.red);
                jTextField2.setForeground(Color.red);
                break;
            } else if (!status1 && status2) { 
                jTextField1.setForeground(Color.red);
                break;
            } else if (status1 && !status2) {
                jTextField2.setForeground(Color.red);
                break;
            }
}
```

**In above code last "if" were not needed at all! as we are inside the while loop surely at least one of two is false and if control comes here the above all "if" must have to be failed! in this situation this if condition will never FAIL!**

**Same result but Simple One: Try it!**

```
    while (!status1 || !status2) {
            if (status1) {                //equivalent to (status1 && !status2) 
                jTextField2.setForeground(Color.red);
                break;

            } else if(status2){           //equivalent to (!status1 && status2) 
                jTextField1.setForeground(Color.red);
                break;
            }
                jTextField2.setForeground(Color.red);
                jTextField1.setForeground(Color.red);            
                break;
}
```